# Visualizing $\det (\exp M+ \exp N)$

Tags: matrices, determinant, visualization, matrix-exponential

I am interested in the follow expression

$$
\det (\exp M+ \exp N)
$$

where $M$ and $N$ are $2\times 2$ real matrices (but also in the general case where the matrices are $n\times n$).

which represents a interference pattern that may have an application in Physics. I am trying to visualize the expression so that I can identify it with something familiar in nature.

The matrices are written as follows:

$$
M=\pmatrix{a+x & -b+y\\b+y & a-x}\\
N=\pmatrix{c+u & -z+v\\z+v & c-u}
$$

Then I can write the matrices as $M=aI + V$ and $N=cI+W$.

In this case,
$$
\begin{array}
\det(\exp aI\exp V + \exp cI \exp W)\\
=(\exp aI\exp V + \exp cI \exp W)(\exp aI\exp -V + \exp cI \exp -W)\\
=(\exp aI)^2+(\exp cI)^2+2\exp aI\exp cI \exp W\exp -V
\end{array}
$$

How can I better visualize this result, considering that my hotel room is currently limited to three spacial dimensions.

edit:

actually the last term should be:

$$
\begin{array}
=(\exp aI)^2+(\exp cI)^2+2\exp aI\exp cI (\exp W\exp -V + \exp V \exp -W)\\
=(\exp aI)^2+(\exp cI)^2+2\exp aI\exp cI (\exp -(V-W) + \exp (V -W))
\end{array}
$$

Comment: I don't see what writing $M=aI+V$ really gives you — your matrices are in general $2x2$ form (that is, any 2x2 matrix can be written in the forms you've described) so it seems as though you're just complicating the situation by introducing your representation.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki This has the similar form of a complex interference pattern in quantum mechanics, except with the full general linear group GL(2,R); rather than just U(1). I am trying to visualize this interference pattern by analogy as the complex interference pattern.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki The first two terms are classical probabilities $(\exp )^2+(\exp )^2$ and the third term is an interference pattern $2\exp  \exp  \exp \exp−$

Comment: what do you mean by "visualizing" ?

Comment: @dezdichado Well that is the tricky part. For a complex interference pattern, I can just draw a cosine on a plane and I know exactly what it is about --- the cosine constructively or destructively shift the probability amplitude up and down according to a phase. Here, there is a phase but it is in multiple dimensions, so it is harder to get a picture thereof. For instance, I need more variable than I can draw. Maybe there is a way to cut sections of the phase to 3D and still create a good image of what is happening. My goal is to find if there is anything in nature which obeys this phase.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by visualizing, you can also write $exp(aI)=\sum (aI)^n/n!= \sum a^nI/n!= e^aI$ so that your second term is just $4e^{a+c}cosh(V-W)$ if you can well define the $cosh$